# Excel 2011 for Mac VBA el capitan

Tags: excel, date, macros, osx-elcapitan, vba

We've had macros running fine in Excel 2011 on a 21.5" iMac running Yosemite 10.10.5.

Having 'upgraded' to a iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2015) running El Capitan 10.11.3, we now find macros failing with Date functions misbehaving. And that's just the first VBA bug we've come across.

Microsoft won't talk about any technical issues unless I pay them $500 and then they may well say they have't had this problem reported to them as their software hasn't changed and I should therefore go to Apple - whereas Apple say that they've had no issuers reported and so I should go to Microsoft!!!

Does anyone have experience of this problem?

Would upgrading to Excel 2016 make any difference?

Is there a workaround?

. . . or should I just downgrade back to Yosemite?

Many thanks,

Jon

. . . Just had a thought, could it simply be the lack of the correct Reference Object Library causing the problem?

June 2nd UPDATE: I've just checked the reference libraries and they're the same as on the Yosemite machine - so back to the original question.

Can someone help me please?

If you have a Mac running ElCapitan and you have Excel 2011 installed, please can you go into an Immediate window in the editor and type '?date' (return) and tell me what you get? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I did eventually find this:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macexcel/vba-for-excel-2011-no-longer-handling-dates-since/3d04e3b6-3cbc-4a36-89e8-323de4f1c7d1

. . . I think points to the fact that it IS a known problem

Jon